How fetch efficiently a gz file with VertX?
I would like to parse efficiently a text file which is compressed on .gz format.
Currently I use the sync api to fetch line and then I send content to an other verticle.
vertx.fileSystem().open("myFile.gz",new OpenOptions(),ar-> {
  if(ar.succeeded()){
    AsyncFile asyncFile = ar.result();
    asyncFile.handler(h -> {
      try(
        ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream (h.getBytes());
        GZIPInputStream gzip = new GZIPInputStream(byteArrayInputStream );
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(gzip);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader)){
          bufferedReader.lines().forEach(line -> vertx.eventBus().send("line",line));
       } catch(Exception ex) {}
    });
}
});

Is there an object to process compressed files in the VertX API?
With Java 21 and VertX 4.5.7
Thx a lot

This boils down to creating a io.vertx.core.streams.ReadStream in order to do the I/O asynchronously and with back-pressure support.
It's not super hard to do on your own, but you can as well use code that has been already created, like this Gist.
Assuming, you went with the aforementioned Gist, the code to read in and handle a GZipped file would look like:
// In your Verticle...
new AsyncInputStream(vertx, context, new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream("test.gz")))
    .exceptionHandler(ex -> System.err.println("ERROR: " + ex.getMessage()))
    .endHandler(__ -> System.out.println("\nDONE"))
    .handler(buffer -> System.out.print(buffer.toString()));

As soon as .handler(...) is executed, the AsyncReadStream starts sending Buffer chunks to the handler.
